# Enviar Imagen con cUrl a Laravel

Tags: curl

Hola estoy intentando enviar una imagen con cUrl hacia un proyecto que tengo en laravel 8, logro conectarme a la funcion del controlador sin problema, pero al hacer un return del $request me percato de que solo veo el temp_name del objeto de la imagen que estoy enviando, no el objeto completo por lo tanto al hacer el ->file en laravel no lo reconoce como obj file, les dejo mis códigos a ver si me pueden indicar que estoy haciendo mal.

```
//array del la imagen que recibo del formulario

C:\wamp64\www\chile\src\ajax\ajaxNuevaImagen.php:118:
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'bikini-bottom.jpeg' (length=18)
  'type' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\php7E07.tmp' (length=25)
  'error' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 206840


//Configuracion en curl

    $ch = curl_init();
    $cfile = new CURLFile($img['tmp_name'][0] ,$img['type'][0] ,$img['name'][0]);
     
    $data = array(
        'img_extra' => $cfile,
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/administracion/public/archivos");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);



//Codigo en laravel

    public function store(Request $req)
    {   
       return $req->img_extra;
    }

//resultado del return donde solo muestra el temp_name

C:\wamp64\www\chile\src\ajax\ajaxNuevaImagen.php:133:string 'C:\wamp64\tmp\php159D.tmp' (length=25)

Tengo la misma funcion implementada directamente en el proyecto en laravel la cual al hacer el return del $request me retorna esto [{}] , y me permite trabajar bien el archivo.

AIUURAAAAA!!!
```

Comment: Revisa este articulo: [Retrieving Uploaded Files](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files)

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione asi

```
if ($img != '') {
        $img_array = array();

        foreach ($img['name'] as $key => $name) {
            $img_array[$key]['name'] = $name;
        }
        foreach ($img['tmp_name']as $key => $temp) {
            $img_array[$key]['tmp'] = $temp;
        }
        foreach ($img['type'] as $key => $type) {
            $img_array[$key]['type'] = $type;
        }
        foreach ($img_array as $key => $value) {
             $data['img_extra[' . $key . ']'] = curl_file_create(
                @$value['tmp'] ,$value['type'],$value['name']
            );
        } 

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/administracion-y-soporte/public/archivos");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
    }
```

Y asi lo recibo con laravel

```
public function store(Request $req)
{   
        if($req->img_extra) {
            foreach($req->file('img_extra') as $file) {
                $archivo= new TbTicketArchvo;
                $dir = 'public/images/';
                $imagename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = $imagename;
                $file->move($dir, $filename);
                $files[] = $dir.$filename;
        $archivo->id_ticket = $req->id_ticket;
        $archivo->ruta = $imagename;
        $archivo->save();
        }
    } 
     return response()->json("ok");
}
```